# Android audio recording, applying Fast Fourier transform

Tags: android, audio

Currently I'm recording audio using [`AudioRecord`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord), more precisely - using it's [`read`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord#read(short[],%20int,%20int)) method overloads that is fed with short buffer (can't use `float[]` one because of min API constraints).

I want to apply [Fast Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) to the data I get during recording. Firstly I convert a received `short[]` to `float[]` using such a conversion:

```
public static float[] convertShortToFloat(short[] array) {
    float[] data = new float[array.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        data[i] = 1.f * array[i] / Short.MAX_VALUE;
    }
    return data;
}
```

Then I just provide the resulting `float[]` to the `FFT` instance and get the result using [`getRealPart()`](https://github.com/jinkg/ETW_Components/blob/70e787d72a858e0550f1bc4c2d5f8d56212a3aae/galaxy_wallpaper/src/main/java/com/mybadlogic/gdx/audio/analysis/FourierTransform.java#L476) method (the implementation of this class I have is actually a bit different, but I believe that it works almost the same as this).

As far as I understand, now I should convert the data I got after transformation back to `short[]` form (convert back to a primal signal domain), and then submit to a muxer. I created a `short[]`-`float[]` array conversion just to be the opposite to the one I've shown earlier, but I just get noise when I play the recording.

What's wrong with the implementation?